# How do you add DateTime to MSDeployDeclareParameters

Tags: msdeploy

What I'm trying to do is use the wpp.targets file in a project to populate a setting in the web.config with the current date time.  This allows you to set potentially a time that msdeploy was run.

So, in the web.config you get:

```
<appsettings>
   <add name="DeploymentDate" value="09/06/2014" />
</appsettings>
```

So in the wpp.targets, what do I put...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using function in the Defaultvalue field like this...

```
  <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="Deployment date">
    <Kind>XmlFile</Kind>
    <scope>Web.config</scope>
    <Match>//appsettings/add[@name='DeploymentDate']/@value</Match>
    <DefaultValue>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))</DefaultValue>
    <Description>The date MsDeploy was run</Description>
    <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
    <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
  </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
```

This only appears to work when the .NET 4.0 version of msdeploy is run.